# dependency spring-boot-starter-test not inherited in multiple module maven project

Tags: spring, maven, testing, junit, dependencies

In my multi-module maven project, all modules have a dependency of my own "common" module, eg, module "A" have this dependency "common".   And the "common" module has a `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency.  However, when I write unit test in this "A" module, it shows that the test dependency not imported.  And then I check the dependencies and found that the `spring-boot-starter-test` is not imported.  I want to ask why?  In my sense, module "A" ref "common", "common" ref `spring-boot-starter-test` , so the module "A" should ref `spring-boot-starter-test`, but the fact is not that.  By the way, in spite of this `spring-boot-starter-test` other dependencies works well via the hirachy.  Does anyone know why it is? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why because the scope is `test` only compile time and non optional dependencies are included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely in the module "A" dependecy `spring-boot-starter-test` has scope `test`. Dependecies with such scope is not transitive. See **Dependency Scope** section https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html.
The best solution is dependency management. See **Dependency Management**

Briefly, you need to create parrent module and declare dependency managment sectoin:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then inherit your modules from parent and just declare dependency without `version` and `scope`

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```